# One-liner for boilerplate code using same argument

Tags: bash

Is there a good one-liner for these three commands using same argument to use `$IMAGE` only once?

```
docker build -t $IMAGE .
docker push $IMAGE
docker rmi $IMAGE
```

Something with an array and a loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a function:

```
bpr() { docker build -t "$1" .; docker push "$1"; docker rmi "$1"; }
```

Now, whenever you want to do those three commands on the same image, run:

```
bpr "$Image"
```

#### Notes

1. If you want make this function definition permanent, put the definition in your `~/.bashrc` file.
2. It is best practices to use mixed case or lower case names for your shell variables.  The system uses upper case names for its variables and you don't want to accidentally overwrite one of them.
3. Note that `$1` is placed inside double-quotes above.  Unless you explicitly want *word splitting* or *pathname expansion*, place your references to shell variables in double-quotes.
4. In bash, white space matters.  In particular, you must leave white space after the `{` in the function definition.

Comment: nice! does `bpr` have any special semantics here?

Comment: @J.Doe No special semantics.  Just put your image name after it.  (Or, were you asking something different?)   Also, FWIW, I chose the name `bpr` from the first letters of build, push, and rmi.   You may, of course, chose any other name you like.